# How to display an image from a blob field

Tags: java, jsp

i'm following this [guide](http://www.roseindia.net/tutorial/java/jsp/jspdisplayblob.html) to understand how to show an image from a blob field.

```
Blob image = null;
byte[ ] imgData = null ;

// here i get the blob and i'm sure that 'image' is not null //////////
image = rsListaNews.getBlob("immagine_principale");    

imgData = image.getBytes(1,(int)image.length());

response.setContentType("image/jpg");
OutputStream o = response.getOutputStream();
o.write(imgData);
o.flush();
o.close();
```

I get this error

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /Include/Chiusura.jsp at line 70

67:     
68:         response.setContentType("image/jpg");
69: 
70:     OutputStream o = response.getOutputStream();
71: 
72:     o.write(imgData);
73:
```

Comment: recieve the image in a byte array

Answer (score 1):

You should not use a JSP to write to the response OutputStream.

You can only ever write to either the response's Writer or it's OutputStream in a single request/response flow but never both. Chances are that somewhere in your JSP, it's already written to the Writer (even if it's only whitespace).

Binary data such as images are better served from a [Servlet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Servlet)

Also, you should never close() the response Writer/OutputStream as this is the container's responsibility.